# How can I make the border bottom of a row more bigger than the others?

Tags: html, css

Actually I want to make the the last border bottom from a table in a page more bigger than the others border bottom, as you can see in the next photo
[image]

The result that I want is this, the last border bottom at the end of the page more bigger
[image]

The css is this

```
.table thead tr td {
                            padding: 1px;
                            color: #000000;
                            background-color: #FFFFFF;
                            border-top: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-left: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-right: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                        }

                        .table tbody tr td {
                            padding: 1px;
                            color: #000000;
                            background-color: #FFFFFF;
                            border-top: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-bottom: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-left: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                            border-right: 1px solid #000000 !important;
                        }
```

Is it posible do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `last-child` selector on last `tr`:

Something like below

```
 .table tbody tr:last-child {   
        border-bottom: 10px solid #000000 !important;
  }
```